# Windows 8 Store app - XmlWriter not creating a file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I am making a Windows 8 store app, and I want to save my data in XML files. I use the code below to write in a XML file. I have tested this code in a console application and it works. It just does not work in my Store app.

```
//Creating a list of projects
                    List<Project> projectslist = new List<Project>();
                    projectslist.Add(new Project(1, "JOTD", new DateTime(2015, 1, 18), new DateTime(2016, 1, 30)));
                    projectslist.Add(new Project(2, "EpicProjects", new DateTime(2016, 1, 31), new DateTime(2016, 5, 30)));

                    //Creating the file 
                    using (XmlWriter writer =  XmlWriter.Create(new StringBuilder("Resources/save.xml")))
                    {
                            writer.WriteStartDocument();
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Projects");

                            //Writing the attributes of the projects
                            foreach (Project item in projectslist)
                            {
                                    writer.WriteStartElement(item._name);
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("name : " + item._name);

                                    writer.WriteElementString("id", item._id.ToString());
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id : " + item._id.ToString());

                                    writer.WriteElementString("startDate", item._startDate.ToString());
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("startDate : " + item._startDate);

                                    writer.WriteElementString("endDate", item._endDate.ToString());
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("endDate : " + item._endDate);

                                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Writing " + item.ToString());
                            }

                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            writer.WriteEndDocument();                          

                    }
```

The file save.xml does not exist before, I want the writer to  create it. However no files are created... :'(

Please do not give me a solution with Streams and await because it causes me an UnauthorizedAccessException and I do not have found ANYTHING that shows how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `XmlWriter.Create(new StringBuilder("Resources/save.xml"))` does not write to any file, it writes to that StringBuilder that you do not even store anywhere.

Comment: Ok so the solution would be that I create a StringBuilder previously, pass it in parameter of Create and then write the StringBuilder in the XML file.  But how do I write this StringBuilder in the file since there is no File class in Store apps ?

Comment: I don't do Windows 8 development, I only saw the post because of the XML and C# tags. As for writing to a StringBuilder, no, I don't think that is the way to go, I would follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx to create a file and open a stream on it, then use `XmlWriter.Create` over that stream. Someone familiar with Windows Phone development needs to tell you the details or resolve any problems you indicate, you might want to edit your question with a sample and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Many thanks ! I am going to try this. The problem is I don't get any error message.

Comment: The UnauthorizedAccessException wasn't because you used streams: it was because you were trying to save the file somewhere the app doesn't have permission to write. The app has read only access to its install folder, read+write to its application data folder, and no access elsewhere except by user permission.